# Satellite path dependence on velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics, satellites

How does a satellite planetary path depend on its speed and other factors.
I want to know more about parabolic, elliptic and hyperbolic paths of satellite.

Comment: This might be helpful. [See this](https://thefactfactor.com/facts/pure_science/physics/critical-velocity-time-period-of-satellite/7247/).

Answer (score 1):

One can tell a whole lot just from the *vis viva* equation,
$$v^2 = GM\left(\frac2r-\frac1a\right) \equiv \mu\left(\frac2r-\frac1a\right)$$
where

- $G$ is the Newtonian gravitation constant,
- $M$ is the mass of the central body,
- $\mu$ is the product of $G$ and $M$,
- $r$ is the current distance from the center of the central body, and
- $a$ is the length of the satellite's semi-major axis.

In orbital mechanics it is typical to prefer to use $\mu$ instead of $GM$ because $\mu$ is directly observable while $M$ is not.

Note that $1/a$ vanishes if $a$ is infinite, in which case the *vis viva* equation reduces to
$$v^2 = \frac{2\mu}r \quad\text{or}\quad v_\text{esc} = \sqrt\frac{2\mu}r$$
An infinite semi-major axis length is **the** condition for a parabolic trajectory. At any point on a parabolic trajectory, the magnitude of the velocity vector will always be equal to the escape velocity. Escape velocity varies with distance from the central body.

A positive but finite semi-major axis length means the orbit is elliptical. When $a$ is positive and finite, the magnitude of the satellite's velocity vector will always be less than escape velocity. A negative but finite semi-major axis length means the trajectory is hyperbolic. When $a$ is negative and finite, the magnitude of the satellite's velocity vector will always be greater than escape velocity.

What about circular orbits? A vehicle in a circular orbit is always orbiting at the same radius, which means $a=r$. In this case the *vis viva* equation reduces to
$$v^2 = \frac{\mu}r \quad\text{or}\quad v_\text{circ} = \sqrt\frac{\mu}r$$